# Am I misusing directives with too much logic?

Tags: angularjs

Let's say I get a list of objects from a `factory`, pass that to a `controller`, and from there render it in a `directive`...So far that's the best practice, right?

Also assuming each object has a `save()` function, if my directive looks like:

```
.directive('Foo', function($modal) {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        require: 'ngModel',
        transclude: true,
        templateUrl: 'admin/foo.html',
        scope: {
            model: '=ngModel',
            save: '&'
        },
        controller: function($scope) {
            $scope.$watch('model', function(newVal, oldVal) {
                init()
            });
            function init(){
              // do some loops
            };
            $scope.doThis(){
             // click event
            }
           $scope.checkThat(){
             // some array methods
            }
           $scope.proxySave(){
             // call passed in fn();
             $scope.save({})
            }
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attr, ngModel) {
          // not really doing much here
        }
```

And from the directive html there's going to be some ng-click functions defined like `doThis()`.

From a separation of concerns perspective I guess it keeps stuff out of my main controller, but I'm not really doing much DOM manipulation inside my directive code, besides linking to a template HTML and a whole bunch of logic in the directive controller. Some of my directive controllers are about 100 lines of logic.

Is it because I'm abusing ng-if's to show/hide? Should I be using the link function instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably your question might be answered more like expressing opinions than offer "right solutions".

I personally wouldn't introduce a controller to a directive if the directive doesn't expose logic which can be used by other directives (`require: "^myDirective"`). So most of my directives have the code you put into the controller in their `link: function (scope, element, attrs) {}`.

But if there are many lines of code which are not related to DOM-manipulation, it is likely that they contain some non-UI-related business logic which could be moved to services. There are better chances of reuse and a clearer separation of concerns.

**TL;DR**

- all `$scope.foo = function () { ... }` can live in `link: function (...) {...}` as well
- if you need a controller to expose some API to other directives, add a controller: `this.bar = function ()`
- put as much logic into services as you can. Or add logic to your model (this is not often seen in AngularJS applications, but I think it's OK)

As I already said: it's just my opinion...

**Edit:** What do I mean with "add logic to your model"?

JavaScript is not only a functional programming language, but can be used object oriented as well. Of course there is no "class", but using protoypal inheritance or ECMAScript 5 features like getters and setters, it's possible to create an object model which looks and behaves like Java or other OOP languages.

There are often very small business logic "snippets", which could be put to controllers, services, filters or directives. I wouldn't connect objects to huge graphs and put all logic (e.g. persistence logic) to the business objects. But these small logic snippets are best located at the model data, e.g.:

```
isExternal()
grossPrice
calculateFields()
roundToMinutes()
```

This gives me security that this kind of logic is always present with the "raw" data and there is a smaller risk of duplicating code. And I don't have to always connect the data with the right services and expose those services in controllers or directives when I need them in the views.

**Edit** Answering "I'm abusing ng-if's to show/hide?"

Complex UI has to show/hide a lot depending on the state of the application and its data. So in real applications (not just small examples) there are quite a lot `ng-if` and `ng-show`/`ng-hide` or `ng-switch`. Doesn't look always good, but what's the alternative? (Sometimes you can save a couple of `ng-if`s if you use `ng-if-start` and `ng-if-end`, see [Multi-Element Directives](http://www.michaelbromley.co.uk/blog/260/writing-multi-element-directives-in-angularjs)).

Comment: I can definitely see spreading more logic into my services, but as far as "add logic to your model" do you mean giving my objects methods to handle operations? aka OOP? That's what I've been thinking of doing.